# How to analyze the order of all children element of XWPFParagraph(CTP) by apache poi

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm trying to analyze a MS Word document with a lot of comment by apache poi.
For example,the content of a paragraph in the *.docx ZIP archive(/word/document.xml) as following:

```
<w:p w14:paraId="4D334472" w14:textId="051ADD4F" w:rsidR="00343D75" w:rsidRDefault="00155A3E">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Before comment</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:commentRangeStart w:id="0"/>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Text with a comment</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:commentRangeEnd w:id="0"/>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rStyle w:val="a3"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:commentReference w:id="0"/>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>After comment</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

We can see that the structure is：

1. a `<w:r>` element with text "Before comment"
2. a `<w:commentRangeStart w:id="0"/>` element
3. a `<w:r>` element with text "Text with a comment" (with a comment)
4. a `<w:commentRangeEnd w:id="0"/>` element
5. a `<w:r>` element with `<w:commentReference w:id="0"/>`
6. a `<w:r>` element with text "After comment"

the 2-6 item is definding the comment, item 1 is the text before the comment and item 6 is the text after the comment.

With apache poi, i can get all `<w:r>` elements, all `<w:commentRangeStart>` elements and all `<w:commentRangeEnd>` elements separately with following code:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/xxxxx.docx");
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(is);
for (XWPFParagraph xwpfParagraph : doc.getParagraphs()) {
    CTP ctp = xwpfParagraph.getCTP();
    CTR[] runs = ctp.getRArray();
    CTMarkupRange[] commentRangeStarts = ctp.getCommentRangeStartArray();
    CTMarkupRange[] commentRangeEnds = ctp.getCommentRangeEndArray();
}
```

but I can't distinguish the order of the items in that three arrays,and the order is important for the next step of my work.How could I know the orders of all child element of the paragraph?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. Programming a better `XWPFCommentsDecorator` which not simply concatenates all comments to a paragraph? Then at first the `<w:commentReference w:id="0"/>` should be of interest. From this you can get the `id` of the comment and then using this `id` you can get the comment `XWPFDocument.getCommentByID` and you can get the `<w:commentRangeStart w:id="0"/>` and `<w:commentRangeEnd w:id="0"/>` with that same `id`.

Comment: Why do you need to know the order of the elements? What are you trying to do? The answer to that may affect the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the order of labels, start with the Dom node, where you can use all the packages under org.apache.xmlbeans

```java
        XmlCursor xmlCursor = ctBody.newCursor();
        while (xmlCursor.hasNextToken()){
            Node node = xmlCursor.getDomNode();
            System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
            xmlCursor.toNextToken();
        }
```

You can get all the node information in the body, here's the node name:

```xml
w:body
w:p
w:rsidR
w:rsidRDefault
w:rsidP
w:pPr
spacing
before
after
beforeLines
afterLines
line
lineRule
spacing
w:ind
w:firstLineChars
w:firstLine
leftChars
rightChars
w:ind
jc
val
jc
rPr
rFonts
hint
eastAsia
hAnsi
ascii
rFonts
rPr
w:pPr
w:r
rPr
rFonts
hint
eastAsia
hAnsi
ascii
rFonts
sz
val
sz
rPr
w:t
w:t
w:r
w:p
```